# Syntaxe error Input field Html using php echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

I' want to show this input via php `echo` but when i remove the readonly property from an input in the following php sentence:

```
    <?
echo '<input class="form-control" name="cant-'.$indice.'+'.($t+1).'" id="cant-'.$indice.'+'.($t+1).'" value="'.$cant_guardada.'" readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';" onblur="this.readOnly='true';">';
 ?>
```

And it's throwing this:
Error: syntax error, unexpected '';" onblur="this.readOnly='' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

I know it's a quote related error but I can't seem to find it, can someone help me!

Comment: At the very least show us the piece of code that throws the error, not the piece of code that works.

Comment: Between PHP Echo statements with double inverted commas never use double inverted commas... Never.(Especially if you are going to write frontend code with attributes)

Comment: Edit! Sorry, copied the error from the same line with onblur added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo '<input class="form-control" name="cant-'.$indice.'+'.($t+1).'" id="cant-'.$indice.'+'.($t+1).'" value="'.$cant_guardada.'" readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly=\'\';">';  ?>
```

The single quotes at `this.readOnly=''` need to be escaped